# jBPM and Object Oriented Programming and Framework

Tags: jbpm

I need to ask a very general question.
I recently saw some sparks of the jBPM through tutorial, what I didn't understand, is where do we need such a tool ?
Is this tool to replace OOP programming ? A developement process ?
In the end, is it possible to generate a BPM which depends to some third party libraries and reuse in that components and logic, as usual a programmer/developer/s.w does ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a BPM System everywhere where you want to expose to business people how your systems are being designed to guide the business use case. Tools like jBPM5 will help you to discover your business processes, formalize them and then automate them. You need to understand the difference with systems integrations where you are only orchestrating which systems to call in which order. In no way BPM is a replacement for OOP or a development methodology, but it helps a lot describe in a higher level / business level what your applications will do, and how your applications will drive the business using the business processes definitions. Just to answer your last question I can say that obviously that you can integrate applications with a BPMS, that's one of the main ideas. Instead of re writing all the applications logic that you have in different systems, BPMS allows you and promote to reuse what your company have.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank yoy for the responce, but could you clarify more the part that you say about 'system integration' and the 'orchestration' ? Can you analyze the terms? Or is there a descent tutorial and can I choose specific tools ( opensource if i can ), and have a dive on this ?

Comment: Hi hephestos, When I was mentioning System Integration I was talking about the fact of having different systems for example: the accounting systems, the tax calculation system, the document management system, etc. and you need to define in which order you need to call them and all the mechanisms that you need to build in order to achieve a task that involve multiple systems.

Comment: Orchestration is mostly the same of defining the order and the sequence to call different systems and how to handle they responses. jBPM5 can be used to define those orchestration, but a BPM system is usually more suitable to describe business situations and not just the interactions of different systems.

Comment: salaboy, quite amazing the explenation of all this! now suppose i wanna build a crud application, with libs of my repository, what tools should i use? also assume this is an rmi project? is there any good,simple rutorial?

Comment: If you want to create a simple CRUD application it doesn't make too much sense, but imagine that you will need BPM when you have multiple CRUDs from different entities and you want to describe the way that the real work needs to be done using those CRUDS.

Comment: jBPM5 and Drools are simple Java libraries that you can embed in your projects, using maven for example. Take a look at my blog inside the Drools and jBPM5 Community training to see code examples and slides :)